# How can i retrieve the email messages which are stored on Device into my application

Tags: android

I have working on one task and I wanted to retrieve the email messages 
which are stored on Device into my application same as we can do with 
SMS messages. Can any one help me that how I can do that? If we cant 
retrieve email messages then any specific reason given by Google or 
Android it self.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this.

You can retrieve SMS because Android provides a content provider to allow you to access the SMS database.

However, Email is mainly handled by two apps: Gmail and the stock Email app. Neither of these apps provide access to their database. Moreover, they only store recent email locally, and pull more from the server when required.

You could always ask the user to sign into their email account using your app, if you really need access to the email.

Comment: Well, in this case how should i go about it then.. I want users all the emails either through other apps of devices or in my app itself... Please suggest..

Comment: Write an email service into your own app.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible as far as I know. reason being that this Email are not stored locally on the devices it's been fetch on the fly and stored when user is logged in.